can't show mpf.plot graph
when i draw graph by axes.plot(x_data, y_data, label='Close Price', color='r'), my program draw graph. but, when i draw a graph by mpf.plot, my program can't draw graph. i could not receive any error message. just not draw. my code is below
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

self.fig = plt.figure()
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
self.d_axes_mgr = DynamicSubplotManager(self.fig) ==> axes management class

try:
    required_columns = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
    for col in required_columns:
       if col not in filtered_df.columns:
          raise ValueError(f"Missing required column: {col}")

    if axes:
       print(f"Axes title: {axes.get_title()}")
       print(f"Axes xlabel: {axes.get_xlabel()}")
       print(f"Axes ylabel: {axes.get_ylabel()}")
       mpf.plot(filtered_df[-100:], type='ohlc', ax=ax, style='charles', returnfig=True, warn_too_much_data=len(filtered_df))                

       # Directly plotting the Close price with a label
       #axes.plot(x_data, y_data, label='Close Price', color='r')
       #print("Line plot completed successfully")


except ValueError as ve:
   print(f"ValueError: {ve}")
except TypeError as te:
   print(f"TypeError: {te}")
except KeyError as ke:
   print(f"KeyError: {ke}")
ex cept Exception as e:
   print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
self.canvas.draw_idle()```



could you help me?



debugging  : axes properties below:
Axes properties: {'_stale': True, 'stale_callback': <function _stale_figure_callback at 0x0000021CC265E7A0>, '_axes': <Axes: >, 'figure': <Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>, '_transform': None, '_transformSet': False, '_visible': True, '_animated': False, '_alpha': None, 'clipbox': None, '_clippath': None, '_clipon': True, '_label': '', '_picker': None, '_rasterized': False, '_agg_filter': None, '_mouseover': False, '_callbacks': <matplotlib.cbook.CallbackRegistry object at 0x0000021CCFD581A0>, '_remove_method': <bound method FigureBase.delaxes of <Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>>, '_url': None, '_gid': None, '_snap': None, '_sketch': None, '_path_effects': [], '_sticky_edges': _XYPair(x=[], y=[]), '_in_layout': True, '_position': Bbox([[0.0, 0.050000000000000044], [0.92, 1.0]]), '_originalPosition': Bbox([[0.0, 0.050000000000000044], [0.92, 1.0]]), '_aspect': 'auto', '_adjustable': 'box', '_anchor': 'C', '_stale_viewlims': {'x': False, 'y': False}, '_forward_navigation_events': 'auto', '_sharex': None, '_sharey': None, 'bbox': <matplotlib.transforms.TransformedBbox object at 0x0000021CCD603D40>, 'dataLim': Bbox([[inf, inf], [-inf, -inf]]), '_viewLim': Bbox([[18927.375, 15781.29], [19926.375, 73072.41]]), 'transScale': <matplotlib.transforms.TransformWrapper object at 0x0000021CCF8A0B30>, 'transAxes': <matplotlib.transforms.BboxTransformTo object at 0x0000021CCFD5A150>, 'transLimits': <matplotlib.transforms.BboxTransformFrom object at 0x0000021CCF8A39B0>, 'transData': <matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform object at 0x0000021CCF8A3290>, '_xaxis_transform': <matplotlib.transforms.BlendedGenericTransform object at 0x0000021CCF8A28D0>, '_yaxis_transform': <matplotlib.transforms.BlendedGenericTransform object at 0x0000021CCF8A0B90>, '_subplotspec': GridSpec(1, 1)[0:1, 0:1], '_box_aspect': None, '_axes_locator': None, '_children': [], '_colorbars': [], 'spines': <matplotlib.spines.Spines object at 0x0000021CCFD5AA20>, 'xaxis': <matplotlib.axis.XAxis object at 0x0000021CCF8A23F0>, 'yaxis': <matplotlib.axis.YAxis object at 0x0000021CCF8A3AA0>, '_facecolor': 'white', '_frameon': True, '_axisbelow': 'line', '_rasterization_zorder': None, 'ignore_existing_data_limits': True, 'callbacks': <matplotlib.cbook.CallbackRegistry object at 0x0000021CCD601BE0>, '_xmargin': 0.05, '_ymargin': 0.05, '_tight': None, '_use_sticky_edges': True, '_get_lines': <matplotlib.axes._base._process_plot_var_args object at 0x0000021CCF8A3B60>, '_get_patches_for_fill': <matplotlib.axes._base._process_plot_var_args object at 0x0000021CCF8A3740>, '_gridOn': False, '_mouseover_set': <matplotlib.cbook._OrderedSet object at 0x0000021CCF8A1850>, 'child_axes': [], '_current_image': None, '_projection_init': (<class 'matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes'>, {}), 'legend_': None, 'containers': [], '_autotitlepos': True, 'title': Text(0.5, 1.0, ''), '_left_title': Text(0.0, 1.0, ''), '_right_title': Text(1.0, 1.0, ''), 'titleOffsetTrans': <matplotlib.transforms.ScaledTranslation object at 0x0000021CCF9DB290>, 'patch': <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x0000021CCF9DB380>, 'axison': True, 'fmt_xdata': None, 'fmt_ydata': None, '_navigate': True, '_navigate_mode': None}


mpf doesn't appear in the imports. Please provide a proper [mre] as right now your code is not even runnable. Also: 1. clarify if "can't show/draw" means that a window/plot appears with nothing in it, or nothing happens at all; 2. run the code in a terminal or prompt, as the IDE may not be able to show all errors or the full traceback.

minimal reproducible example, please
